# String only accepts certain characters

Tags: java, string

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Code");

        String code = input.next();
    }

    public static boolean isValidCode (String code) {

    }
}
```

I'm having a lot of trouble in java when I try to make restrictions on input. In this example, I need the string code to only accept symbols such as `$` and `%`. How can I check to make sure there are no numbers,letters, or other symbols?
Thanks

Comment: You can use [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info).

Comment: @maba: You should post that as an answer! But you might want to give a Java-specific link as well, such as http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html.

Comment: I see regular expressions for numbers and letters but not this specific.

Comment: @ruakh There's gonna be tons of answers for this question. People are so eager to earn some reps so they will easily go for this one. It's like when you see a question about String comparison. Ten answers immediately.

Comment: @Tooilia: You'll have to create your own "character class". Like "[%$&_]"

Comment: Ok, so whats the structure you use to do that?

Comment: See m3th0dman's answer. Here's a good tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 6):

This should work to invalidate strings that contain anything except `$` and/or `%`:

```
public static boolean isValidCode (String code) {
    return code.matches("^[$%]*$");
}
```

If you also require that the string not be empty, then change the `*` to a `+`. If you need to accept other characters, just add them to the character class list (the characters between the square brackets).

If the test is going to be done many times (which isn't the case in your posted code), it would be more efficient to pre-compile the pattern:

```
private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[$%]*$");

public static boolean isValidCode (String code) {
    return p.matcher(code).matches();
}
```

(The call to `code.matches(...)` is just a convenience method does the above.)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isValidCode(String code) {
    return code.matches("[$%]*");
}
```

As you can see in regex javadoc, the angle brackets say that you can choose between the enclosing characters ($ and % in your case); * say that it must appear 0 or more times.

Comment: You might want to put `"`s around that regex.

Comment: No, `*` says that it can appear _0 or more_ times, you are thinking of `+`.

Comment: Even if you change the `*` to `+`, that will match any string that has at least one of `$` or `%`. You need anchors at each end.

Comment: Ted's right. I would negate it, though. Like "if the string is being matched containing one character NOT in the class then it is NOT valid". Should be easier. At least that's what I understood the op wants.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Character` Class.

**Here is the Code for you :**

```
public class Hello {




    public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Code");

     String code = input.next();
     char c = code.charAt(0);
    if( (!Character.isDigit(c)) && (!Character.isLetter(c) && (!Character.isWhitespace(c)))){

        if(c == '%' || c=='$'){

            System.out.println("Its what u want");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Not what u want");
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Not what u want$");
    }


     }



}
```

Comment: Yeesh--no! This is a job for regular expression matching, not do-it-yourself validation.

Comment: @TedHopp did OP mentioned that this has to be strictly done using Regex. Every programmer won't think the same.... we all have our own ways to solve a problem..... So please don't be judgmental about what should be used and what should not be... let the OP select which best suits his or her needs... thanks

Comment: If OP asks for a solution using Regex, then why post an answer that does not use Regex?

Comment: @TedHopp please read the OP's question.. he never mentioned regex

Comment: Yes, you're right that Regex is not required. Nevertheless, a single Regex match is much clearer than half a dozen lines of logic. Besides, your answer only is correct for strings of length 1. It will incorrectly approve of multi-character strings that start with `$` or `%`, and it will throw an exception with empty strings.

Comment: @TedHopp Yes it is for a String of length one, cause if you read the code of OP, he has used next() instead of nextLine(), so `he mean JUST ONE CHARACTER....`... its very important to read the code of a programmer and then his explanations to get the gist of his requirements

Comment: Please read the docs for `Scanner.next()`. It returns the next _token_ (as determined by the current delimiters--defaulting to whitespace characters), not the next character.

Comment: I mean multiple occurrence of `$` or `%` in the entire String which include multiples words

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Code");

        String code = input.next();
        for(int i=0;i<code.length();i++)
        {
            char c = code.charAt(i);

            if((!Character.isDigit(c))&&(!Character.isLetter(c)&&(!Character.isWhitespace(c))))      
            {
                if(c=='%'||c=='$')
                {
                    //What U Want..........
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Plz! Enter Only '%' or '$'");
                    break;
                }
            }//if
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Allows Only '%' or '$' Symbols");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```